# Why do companies do custom-development in SharePoint? Can you give me some use cases?

Tags: development

Can you give me some examples of what companies are custom-developing SharePoint for?

I'm trying to see what are they trying to get that SharePoint doesn't offer (not talking about UI customization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharePoint is a generic product provided by Microsoft that can be customized according to business needs, since every company has different business needs and processes so they can either compromise and use the SharePoint the way it is or they customize it to make it simple.

My company customized SharePoint in a way that every company can use it to fill there governance needs. Here's the list of products we developed using SharePoint.

http://www.eshare.co.uk/BoardAssuranceSoftware/Pages/default.aspx

Out of box SharePoint might look attractive to you for first time but its doesn't really provide everything a company might need.

Microsoft developed a general framework or product for almost every business, now each business can crave it in the way they want it.